# Android: Drawing horizontal bar charts with `MPAndroidChart`

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am trying to draw a Horizontal bar chart in android using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Please check the below code.

**activity_mail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.graphs.graphs2.MainActivity">



    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HorizontalBarChart chart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        BarData data = new BarData(getDataSet());
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
        chart.invalidate();
    }

    private BarDataSet getDataSet() {

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList();
                entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
                entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
                entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
                entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
                entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
                entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));

        BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries,"hi");
        return dataset;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList();
                labels.add("January");
                labels.add("February");
                labels.add("March");
                labels.add("April");
                labels.add("May");
                labels.add("June");
        return labels;
    }


}
```

This gave me the following chart.
[image]

However, the bar chart I want is like below...
[image]

So I need to do few things...

1. Colour the bars
2. Remove guide lines
3. Show the description of each bar at the left side of it
4. Display the "%" mark with numbers at the end of bars (ex: for the first bar, display `4%` instead of `4`)

I visited this post as well, the authher of the library seems to have done some of what I requested, so probably possible with this library. How can I do them?

Answer (score 9):

**Colouring the bars:**

`BarDataSet#setColor(List<Integer>)`

**Remove grid lines:**

```
chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
chart.getLeftAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
```

**Show description:**

Add a text view separately to the chart

**Adding % to values:**

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return (int) Math.floor(value) + "%";
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541099/set-the-negative-values-to-the-left-of-the-bars-in-horizontal-bar-chart?noredirect=1#comment105254330_59541099

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.graphs.graphs2.MainActivity">



    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

InsightActivity.java

```
package com.animedix.health_hive.buzz.insights;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.animedix.health_hive.R;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class InsightsActivity extends Activity {


    TextView Firstday, Secondday, Thirdday, Fourthday, Fifthday, SixthDay, Seventhday,
            Firstdate, Seconddate, Thirddate, Fourthdate, Fifthdate, SixthDate, Seventhdate,tool_title;
    Toolbar toolbar_insight;
    ImageView img_back;
    Calendar Todaydate;
    HorizontalBarChart barChart,second_barchart,third_barchart,fourth_barchart,fifth_barchart,sixth_barchart,seventh_barchart;
    ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1,bargroup2,bargroup3,bargroup4,bargroup5,bargroup6,bargroup7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insight);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        /*Date date = c.getTime();
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        System.out.println("Current time => " + day);*/

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        Log.e("today","today "+formattedDate);


        toolbar_insight = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_insight);
        img_back = (ImageView) toolbar_insight.findViewById(R.id.img_back);
        Firstday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_first_day);
        Secondday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_second_day);
        Thirdday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_third_day);
        Fourthday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fourth_day);
        Fifthday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fifth_day);
        SixthDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_sixth_day);
        Seventhday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_seventh_day);
        Firstdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_first_date);
        Seconddate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_second_date);
        Thirddate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_third_date);
        Fourthdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fourth_date);
        Fifthdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fifth_date);
        SixthDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_sixth_date);
        Seventhdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_seventh_date);
        tool_title = (TextView) toolbar_insight.findViewById(R.id.txt_careteam);
        tool_title.setText("The Buzz");

        tool_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        img_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date myDate = null;
        try {
            myDate = dateFormat.parse(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar.setTime(myDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);


        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date myDate1 = null;
        try {
            myDate1 = dateFormat1.parse(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar1.setTime(myDate1);
        calendar1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -6);

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date myDate2 = null;
        try {
            myDate2 = dateFormat2.parse(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar2.setTime(myDate2);
        calendar2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -5);


        Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date myDate3 = null;
        try {
            myDate3 = dateFormat3.parse(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar3.setTime(myDate3);
        calendar3.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -4);


        Calendar calendar4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat4 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date myDate4 = null;
        try {
            myDate4 = dateFormat4.parse(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar4.setTime(myDate4);
        calendar4.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3);


        Calendar calendar5 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat5 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date myDate5 = null;
        try {
            myDate5 = dateFormat5.parse(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar5.setTime(myDate5);
        calendar5.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -2);


        Calendar calendar6 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat6 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date myDate6 = null;
        try {
            myDate6 = dateFormat6.parse(formattedDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar6.setTime(myDate6);
        calendar6.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);


        Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
        Date newDate1 = calendar1.getTime();
        Date newDate2 = calendar2.getTime();
        Date newDate3 = calendar3.getTime();
        Date newDate4 = calendar4.getTime();
        Date newDate5 = calendar5.getTime();
        Date newDate6 = calendar6.getTime();


        Log.e("test", "test" + newDate.toString());
        Log.e("test", "test" + newDate1.toString());
        Log.e("test", "test" + newDate2.toString());
        Log.e("test", "test" + newDate3.toString());
        Log.e("test", "test" + newDate4.toString());
        Log.e("test", "test" + newDate5.toString());
        Log.e("test", "test" + newDate6.toString());



        Log.e("substring",newDate.toString().substring(0, Math.min(newDate.toString().length(), 10)));
        String date=newDate.toString().substring(0, Math.min(newDate.toString().length(), 10));
        String date1=newDate1.toString().substring(0, Math.min(newDate1.toString().length(), 10));
        String date2=newDate2.toString().substring(0, Math.min(newDate2.toString().length(), 10));
        String date3=newDate3.toString().substring(0, Math.min(newDate3.toString().length(), 10));
        String date4=newDate4.toString().substring(0, Math.min(newDate4.toString().length(), 10));
        String date5=newDate5.toString().substring(0, Math.min(newDate5.toString().length(), 10));
        String date6=newDate6.toString().substring(0, Math.min(newDate6.toString().length(), 10));
        String[] day = date.split(" ");
        String[] day1 = date1.split(" ");
        String[] day2 = date2.split(" ");
        String[] day3 = date3.split(" ");
        String[] day4 = date4.split(" ");
        String[] day5 = date5.split(" ");
        String[] day6 = date6.split(" ");
        Firstday.setText(day[0]);
        Firstdate.setText(day[2] + "/" +day[1]);
        Secondday.setText(day1[0]);
        Seconddate.setText(day1[2] + "/" +day[1]);
        Thirdday.setText(day2[0]);
        Thirddate.setText(day2[2] + "/" +day[1]);
        Fourthday.setText(day3[0]);
        Fourthdate.setText(day3[2] + "/" +day[1]);
        Fifthday.setText(day4[0]);
        Fifthdate.setText(day4[2] + "/" +day[1]);
        SixthDay.setText(day5[0]);
        SixthDate.setText(day5[2] + "/" +day[1]);
        Seventhday.setText(day6[0]);
        Seventhdate.setText(day6[2] + "/" +day[1]);



        barChart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);
        second_barchart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.second_barchart);
        third_barchart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.third_barchart);
        fourth_barchart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.fourth_barchart);
        fifth_barchart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.fifth_barchart);
        sixth_barchart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.sixth_barchart);
        seventh_barchart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.seventh_barchart);


        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        /*bargroup1 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(8f, 0));
        bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(6f, 1));

        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        bargroup2 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(2f, 0));
        bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(10f, 0));


        bargroup3 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup3.add(new BarEntry(5f, 0));
        bargroup3.add(new BarEntry(25f, 0));


        bargroup4 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup4.add(new BarEntry(6f, 0));
        bargroup4.add(new BarEntry(10f, 0));


        bargroup5 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup5.add(new BarEntry(6f, 0));
        bargroup5.add(new BarEntry(10f, 0));

        bargroup6 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup6.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
        bargroup6.add(new BarEntry(17f, 0));

        bargroup7 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup7.add(new BarEntry(17f, 0));
        bargroup7.add(new BarEntry(17f, 0));

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(bargroup1, "Bar Group 1");
        barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(bargroup2, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet3 = new BarDataSet(bargroup3, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet3.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet4 = new BarDataSet(bargroup4, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet4.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet5 = new BarDataSet(bargroup5, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet5.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet6 = new BarDataSet(bargroup6, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet6.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet7 = new BarDataSet(bargroup7, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet7.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();*/

        /*ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        *//*dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet3);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet4);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet5);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet6);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet7);*//*
        BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataSets); // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet

        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.setDescription("Set Bar Chart Description");  // set the description
        barChart.animateY(5000);*/



        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(18f, 0));
        bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(28f, 1));
        bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(18f, 2));
        bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(48f, 3));

        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup2 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(6f, 0));

        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup3 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup3.add(new BarEntry(9f, 0));
        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup4 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup4.add(new BarEntry(16f, 0));
        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup5 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup5.add(new BarEntry(26f, 0));
        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup6 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup6.add(new BarEntry(36f, 0));
        // create BarEntry for Bar Group 1
        ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup7 = new ArrayList<>();
        bargroup7.add(new BarEntry(46f, 0));


        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(bargroup1, "");  // creating dataset for group1

        //barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
        barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(bargroup2, ""); // creating dataset for group1
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet3 = new BarDataSet(bargroup3, ""); // creating dataset for group1
        barDataSet3.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarDataSet barDataSet4 = new BarDataSet(bargroup4, ""); // creating dataset for group1
        barDataSet4.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarDataSet barDataSet5 = new BarDataSet(bargroup5, ""); // creating dataset for group1
        barDataSet5.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarDataSet barDataSet6 = new BarDataSet(bargroup6, ""); // creating dataset for group1
        barDataSet6.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarDataSet barDataSet7 = new BarDataSet(bargroup7, ""); // creating dataset for group1
        barDataSet7.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("");
        labels.add("");
        labels.add("");
        labels.add("");


        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataSets); // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
        barChart.setData(data);

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets1 = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
        dataSets1.add(barDataSet2);
        BarData data1 = new BarData(labels, dataSets1); // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
        second_barchart.setData(data1);

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets2 = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
        dataSets2.add(barDataSet3);
        BarData data2 = new BarData(labels, dataSets2); // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
        third_barchart.setData(data2);

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets3 = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
        dataSets3.add(barDataSet4);
        BarData data3 = new BarData(labels, dataSets3); // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
        fourth_barchart.setData(data3);


        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets4 = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
        dataSets4.add(barDataSet5);
        BarData data4 = new BarData(labels, dataSets4); // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
        fifth_barchart.setData(data4);


        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets5 = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
        dataSets5.add(barDataSet6);
        BarData data5 = new BarData(labels, dataSets5); // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
        sixth_barchart.setData(data5);


        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets6 = new ArrayList<>();  // combined all dataset into an arraylist
        dataSets6.add(barDataSet6);
        BarData data6 = new BarData(labels, dataSets6); // initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
        seventh_barchart.setData(data6);



        barChart.animateY(3000);
        second_barchart.animateY(3000);
        third_barchart.animateY(3000);
        fourth_barchart.animateY(3000);
        fifth_barchart.animateY(3000);
        sixth_barchart.animateY(3000);
        seventh_barchart.animateY(3000);

        barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

        barChart.getDrawingCache(false);

        barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);


        second_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        second_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

        second_barchart.getDrawingCache(false);

        second_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

        second_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        second_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);

        third_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        third_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

        third_barchart.getDrawingCache(false);

        third_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

        third_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        third_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);

        fourth_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        fourth_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

        fourth_barchart.getDrawingCache(false);

        fourth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

        fourth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        fourth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);

        fifth_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        fifth_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

        fifth_barchart.getDrawingCache(false);

        fifth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

        fifth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        fifth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);

        sixth_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        sixth_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

        sixth_barchart.getDrawingCache(false);

        sixth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        sixth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        sixth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        sixth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        sixth_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

        sixth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        sixth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        sixth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        sixth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        sixth_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);


        seventh_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        seventh_barchart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        seventh_barchart.getDrawingCache(false);

        seventh_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);
        seventh_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        seventh_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        seventh_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        seventh_barchart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

        seventh_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawZeroLine(false);
        seventh_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        seventh_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
        seventh_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        seventh_barchart.getAxisRight().setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false);





    }

}
[I need to remove top & below entry of the chart 10,20,30 & remove description in Chart..][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUMcl.png
```

Comment: Please give some explanation about your answer.